# Call to undefined method Illuminate\View\View::make() laravel 5.3 not redirected to the view

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I am trying to redirect after deleting a user from `user` table.
Everything works fine, but after deleting the user I am not redirected to same page.

This is my `AdminController` `index` method

```
public function index()
{
    //$users = DB::table('users')->get();

    $users = DB::table('users')
        ->where('is_active', 1)
        ->get();


    //return  view('adminpage', ['users' => $users]);
    return View::make('adminpage',['users' => $users]);

}

// delete function in `AdminController`

public function destroy($id)
{
    User::destroy($id);

     return Redirect::to('/admin');
}
```

here is my route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin']], function () {
    Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index');
    Route::resource('/deleteuser', 'AdminController');

    Route::get('/adduser', function () {
      return view('adduser');
    });
});
```

Why am I not redirected to `adminpage`, If I use simple

```
//return  view('adminpage', ['users' => $users]);
```

I only get to go to the view. But then after deleting the record I get below error.

> FatalThrowableError in AdminController.php line 105:  Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Redirect' not found

When I use

```
return View::make('adminpage',['users' => $users]);
```

I can even go to the view,

Why `View::make` doesn't work, and why am I not redirected to `adminpage`.
Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Redirect` is a facade for a redirect response and therefore needs to be included in the current namespace.

Add `use Redirect` alongside your other `use` declarations, after your `namespace` declaration.

Alternatively, you can use the `redirect()` helper.

```
return redirect()->to('/admin');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use redirect()->route("admin");

Comment: That didnt work,
Also  redirect()->route("/admin"); Didn't work.